# Working on Sign up page with ASP .net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm an intern developer and learning to code in ASP .net with mvc framework.

I'm working on a sign up page for a website where the users have to click on the link provided to validate their account with a website while registering their account.

Now, if the users have not clicked on the link which was sent to them in an email while registering then the user will not have a valid account and for those users I want that this message should be displayed "Please confirm your link to activate your account".

For that my code is as below but this code is giving me errors while I run it (looks like it is not going into the else condition.

My code is as below and is not working. Can someone please help me on this-

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            Session["CheckAmountOfSites"] = true;
            ViewBag.SuggestBrowser = false;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {

                    model.UserName = model.UserName.Trim().ToLower();

                    if (ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                    {
                        if (activated == true)
                        {
                            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName.ToLower(), model.RememberMe);
--Some more stuffs in if condition but have not been pasted completely here for --security reasons
} }
```

This is my else condition--But somehow its not entering the else part.

```
//validate user is not true
                else
                {
                    //ModelState.AddModelError("", "The Email or Password provided is incorrect.");
                    if (activated == false)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Account", new { userName = model.UserName });
                    }

                }
```

Confirm action--

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Confirm( string userName)
        {
            using (var db = SiteUtil.NewDb)
            {
                var user = db.Users.Where(n => n.Username == userName && n.CanLogin == false).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user.CanLogin == false)
                {
                    ViewBag.Email = "Please confirm your mail to activate your account";

                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        public bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            using (var db = SiteUtil.NewDb)
            {
                var user = db.Users.Where(n => n.Username == userName  && n.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (user.CanLogin == false)
                {


                    //Mod("Email", "please confirm the mail which was sent to you");
                    //ViewBag.Email = "please confirm the mail which was sent to you";
                    return true;



                }
```

Comment: Hi mamta is the problem once they have clicked the url in the email you have sent?

Comment: May I know where do you assign the value for `activated`??

Comment: Also is your `if (user.CanLogin == false)` suppose to `return false;` ?

Comment: Hi David, Not really the problem is not once they have clicked the url in the email. The problem is if they have not clicked the link in the url then the account is not valid. So , I'm expecting to display the message to that user that "Please confirm your account  by clicking on the link present in your email". So my execution flow doesn't go to the sign up page first of all , it goes to the parent project of which my current project is part of.

Comment: Hi Shawn If you see my first code inside   Validateuser () I have assigned value  if (activated == true)

Comment: if (user.CanLogin == false) should return True as the user is not active , They have to activate the account.

Comment: So you have already declared `activated` as `boolean` elsewhere?

Comment: @Mamta you should return False actually , then only you will move to your else statement

Comment: Try to debug and see the value of `if (ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))`

Comment: I have defined activated as a global variable as boolean

Comment: Ok do you assign a default value for `activated`?

Comment: Try to remove `if(activated == true)` and `if(activated == false)`.Hope it wokrs

Comment: I have kept the condition as True                                                             I have not created any confirm view for this, do I have to create a confirm view for this? After debugging I saw its going to else part but after going to confirm action method its giving me error as below          The view 'Confirm' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:                        /Areas/ProgramFinder/Views/Account/Confirm.cshtml

Comment: add a view and pass your `ViewBag.Email` into it

Comment: Ah I see..because your condition is True thats why when it goes to else part your activated value is True so your redirectoaction is not returned

Comment: O my Godddddd!!!! It worked Shawn !!!! Thank you soooo much . I removed the default value that I assigned to activated , then I created view for Confirm and passed my ViewBag.Email into it and it displayed a message "Please confirm your mail to activate your account" and this is what I'm after. Thank you so much Shawn!! Legend!!!

Comment: Np @Mamta, glad to help. :-)

Comment: Rmb to post your own answer as it might help future readers.Cheers!